# What is the function of 贴 in 四贴袋？

Tags: meaning

I can't figure out what 贴 is doing here:

中国革命先行者孙中山综合了西式服装与中式服装的特点，设计出了一种直翻领有袋盖的四贴袋男用套装，定名为中山装，此后几十年，中山装大为流行，成为中国男子喜欢的标准服装。

‘四贴袋‘ is 贴 a 量词 here?

Comment: dict.cn: 贴袋 patch pocket，it may be that this functions as a 准量词，thus does not require an additional 量词

Comment: Aha, so it's a pocket sewn onto the outside of the suit?

Answer (score 3):

贴 in 四贴袋 is not measure word but adjective, meaning *pasted*. It describes the appearance of the pocket is like it's pasted/patched on the suit.

When 贴袋 is used as noun, you can use any measure word that's applicable to a pocket. E.g.

> 这件衣服上有四**个**贴袋。

But in your example, 四贴袋 is noun-as-adjective (数词+名词短语做定语), in which situation there should not be measure words in between, and strictly speaking, 四 here is not nominal number *four* but tuple nomenclature *quad*. Some other examples:

> 三轮车 three-wheel(ed) vehicle
>
> 多功能全自动洗衣机 multi-function automatic washing machine
>
> 四贴袋男用套装 four/quad-patch pocket men's suit

Comment: The sense of this is 'pockets that are sewn onto the suit' rather than integrated into the suit with just a little flap to cover the slit where the pocket is? You can see the pocket and the stitching? 有袋盖 = has pocket flaps ??

Comment: @Pedroski Yes and yes.

Comment: (数词+名词短语做定语)：（dict。cn）他正在服3个月的缓刑，3个月的缓刑，（iciba翻译）3个月的监禁判决 also：32根辐条的轮组，

Comment: @user6065 Those are not 定语 (attributive modifier)...

Comment: 四贴袋 and examples in answer characterized by absence of 的, however also note 捷安特32根辐条轮组最便宜也最耐用 http://bbs.biketo.com/thread-780672-1-1.html