# What's wrong with 一个年?

Tags: measure-word

From what I can tell, `一个年` is completely wrong because you can never use a classifier together with `年`. The situation is different from a phrase like `一个朋友`.

My question is: why? Is there a reason why `年` is different from `朋友` like this? Are there other nouns which behave like `年`?

Or is `年` really syntactically more like `个`? Is `年` actually usable as a measure word? Can you for example say `一年时间` or `两年工作`?

Comment: see any grammar: CCG:2.11 Missing measure words ...one possibility is that the noun itself may be  a measure. E.g. 一个人，一人，e。g。一人船，一个星期、一星期，e。g。一星期假期，there is some ambiguity with temporal nouns, some are only nouns, some may be both nouns and measures, while others may be only used as measures: 一个小时，一小时，一个钟头，＊一钟头，＊一个天，一天，一个礼拜，＊一礼拜，一周，一个周，一个月, 一月 (January)，＊一个年，一年

Comment: also note  数词+名词短语做定语, e.g. 一人船, 四贴袋男用套装  https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/14657/what-is-the-function-of-%e8%b4%b4-in-%e5%9b%9b%e8%b4%b4%e8%a2%8b

Comment: You may speak 一日/一天, 一星期/一个星期/一周/一个周, 一月(depending on context)/一个月, 一年, you may not speak 一个日/一个天, 一个年. The word 一月 would mean **one month** or **January**. If you say 这一月, it means **this one month**, or you may speak **一** with second tone, **yí**, and stress the character 月, it means **one month** but not **January**. **January** reads as **yī** (first tone) **yue** (untoned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot say 一个年, but you can say 一个年头

The difference between 年 and 年头 had been explained here  [Understanding 年頭 in context](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21066/understanding-%e5%b9%b4%e9%a0%ad-in-context/21068#21068)

Yes, 年 itself can be a classifier  '一年时间' and '两年工夫' are both valid

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers said, 年 is a measure word when it refers to 'year', i.e. 一年时间, 两年工作.

Well, when 年 is used as a noun, it specifically refers to the Spring Festival, 新年.

For example,

> 你在中国过了几个（新）年了？ // How many Spring Festivals have you spent in China
>
> 这（一）个年怎么过 or 这（一）个新年怎么过 // How are we going to celebrate this Spring Festivals?

Comment: should be the accepted answer. Others failed to consider when 年 is a noun, 一个年 is correct.

Comment: 年 may also means [a monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nian), which is a noun

Comment: 新年 is a countable noun, 年 is a short form of it. The correct phrasing should be "你在中国过了几个新年了",  writing "你在中国过了几个年了 could be  "你在中国过了几个年头了 ". In short,  '年' being a noun only when it is the short form of either '新年' or  '年头'. Finally, saying  '一个年' is a short form of '一个年头'  or  '一个新年'-- people usually don't shorten these two phrases like that.

Comment: the noun 年 by itself doesn't take classifier,

Comment: @TangHo, 一个年 is usually short for 一个新年, but not 一个年头. 年头 should not be elided.

Answer (score 1):

Because 年 is a count word or classifier. In our language it is called 量词. You can't use a count word to count another count word, like we never say 一个粒 or 一条只. But you use the double count words to express *every*, like 一年年 means every year.